# Adding items to Android React Native Developer menu

Tags: android, react-native

In React Native when making development builds you can shake the device or use the menu button to bring up a developer menu.  How do you add an additional custom item to this menu?  I haven't been able to find any documentation on adding another item but I think it would be very handy to say toggle between server environments (dev, prod, etc.) from the dev menu rather than making separate builds to test against each environment.

Comment: I don't think there's any documentation, but it looks like it's here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/React/Modules/RCTDevMenu.m

Comment: @DanLeveille it looks like the link is dead :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [DevSettings](https://reactnative.dev/docs/devsettings#addmenuitem) `addMenuItem` function to add item in React Native developer menu

in your main `App.js` component, write

```js
import { DevSettings } from 'react-native';

//...

useEffect(() => {
    // componentDidMount

    // Add our toggle command to the menu
    DevSettings.addMenuItem('Toggle Storybook', () => {
        // Perform your logic here
    });
}, []);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `DevSupportManager` class can do this for you. You can get it from your `ReactNativeHost` instance via its `ReactInstanceManager`:

```
ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager = reactNativeHost.getReactInstanceManager();
DevSupportManager devSupportManager = reactInstanceManager.getDevSupportManager();
```

With that in hand, add a custom dev option as follows:

```
devSupportManager.addCustomDevOption("Custom dev option", new DevOptionHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onOptionSelected() {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hello from custom dev option", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Where you get hold of your `ReactNativeHost` instance in the first place depends on how you've structured your app. If you created the app using `react-native init`, your main application class will include this:

```
@Override
public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
}
```

...which you could call.

[I have a complete sample here](https://github.com/petterh/react-native-android-activity); look at [MainActivity](https://github.com/petterh/react-native-android-activity/blob/master/android/app/src/main/java/com/demo/activity/MainActivity.java).OnCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MainApplication application = (MainApplication) getApplication();
    ReactNativeHost reactNativeHost = application.getReactNativeHost();
    ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager = reactNativeHost.getReactInstanceManager();
    DevSupportManager devSupportManager = reactInstanceManager.getDevSupportManager();
    devSupportManager.addCustomDevOption("Custom dev option", new DevOptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onOptionSelected() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hello from custom dev option", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```